Adding "via" tag when sending emails with SMTP in Laravel
I'm trying to implement a feature in my Laravel project where emails sent from a specific address, let's say "info@example.com," are marked with a "via" tag indicating they were sent via a particular server, for instance, "example-server.com". Essentially, the email header should reflect that the email was sent from "info@example.com" via "example-server.com".
I've attempted to achieve this by modifying the configuration in Laravel for SMTP, but haven't had success. Could someone provide guidance or a solution on how to accomplish this in Laravel? Any insights or code examples would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

I guess using a Laravel Mail Closures should be done right here.
The headers method allows you to add custom headers like "X-Via" with the desired server name.
    Mail::send('your-email-template', $data, function ($message) use 
    ($serverName) {
    $message->from('info@example.com')
          ->subject('Your Email Subject')
          ->to('recipient@example.com')
          ->headers('X-Via', $serverName); // Add your custom header here
    });


It doesn't work as the message doesn't have the headers function. Also, using Laravel mail doesn't add via tag on emails. Are there any issues with SPF, DKIM, or DMARC records?
